# Client side filtering using useReducer

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I have a transactions table, which contains some data. I am trying to make client side filter onChange of search input.

It works at first, to the next onChange event it filters the previously filtered data and not the initial data.

How can I make it that it always filter the initial state on every onChange event?

If there is a better approach of doing this, please tell me

```
//Table
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useReducer(
    transactionsReducer,
    fetchTransactions()
  )
```

```
//Reducer
const transactionsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'filter':
      return action.transactions.filter(item =>
        item.description.includes(action.searchTerm)
      )

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

```
//Search component (it receives setTransactions function as a prop)
const Search = ({ setTransactions }) => {
  const handleChange = event => {
    setTransactions({
      type: 'filter',
      searchTerm: event.target.value
    })
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <Input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="search"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your reducer should return both the original data as well as filtered data. Currently the reducer is returning only the filtered data so next time the `onChange` is called, so `filter` works on the previously filtered data. Or you can take another approach by filtering within `onChange` and set the filtered value in another local state.

Comment: I am trying not to use another state for this. 
"Your reducer should return both the original data as well as filtered data"
how exaclty can I do this?

Comment: Basically your initial state for `useReducer` would have a shape like `{transaction: fetchTransactions(), filtered: []}`. When you dispatch `filter` type, your reducer should filter `filtered = yourFilterFunction(state.transactions)` and return it like `{...state, filter: filtered}`.

And you can access the filtered transactions as `transactions.filtered` inside your component

Answer (score 0):

I passed the transactions to the Search component from fetchTransactions() like this

```
<Search
  setTransactions={setTransactions}
  transactions={fetchTransactions()}
/>
```

and then pass this transactions to my reducer as action:

```
const handleChange = event => {
   setTransactions({
     type: 'filter',
     transactions, //like this
     searchTerm: event.target.value
   })
}
```

and filter through this transactions in my reducer:

```
const transactionsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'filter':
      return action.transactions.filter(item =>
        item.description.includes(action.searchTerm)
      )

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and it works fine. If there is a better approaches to this, please let me know